# alignment of components using adf components

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

How can I align the different components equi-spaced using adf components?

E.g.:

```
label : drop down
label : drop down
label : drop down
```

Is there any component available in adf such that I just have to put the output text and drop down in the tags and it will be aligned equi spaced properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a `panelGrid`.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  lbl1
  dropdown1
  lbl2
  dropdown2
  lbl3
  dropdown3
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: hey Balus, i want to use adf component. Currently i have used the same approach as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Use an af:PanelForm to surround your components - then you can set label and field width properties on that panelForm

Like:

```
            <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1" fieldWidth="200" labelWidth="150">
            <af:inputText label="Label 1" id="it1"/>
            <af:inputListOfValues label="Label 1" popupTitle="Search and Result Dialog" id="ilov1"/>
            <af:inputText label="Label 2" id="it2"/>
            <af:inputText label="Label 3" id="it3"/>
        </af:panelFormLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Shay, Can you please give me a code snippet for the same. Also please let me know where to place this tag in the page. thanks..

Comment: Something like this:             <af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1" fieldWidth="200" labelWidth="150">
                <af:inputText label="Label 1" id="it1"/>
                <af:inputListOfValues label="Label 1" popupTitle="Search and Result Dialog" id="ilov1"/>
                <af:inputText label="Label 2" id="it2"/>
                <af:inputText label="Label 3" id="it3"/>
            </af:panelFormLayout>